# Template parameters of function type with auto return type arguments of previous template parameter types

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, language-lawyer

I have a template with two parameters: the first is a type, and the second is a function pointer with an argument whose type is the first template parameter. This MCVE works:

```
void returnsVoid(int x) { }

template <typename T, void (*Func)(T)>
struct foo { void bar(T t) { Func(t); } };

int main(int, char *[]) {
    foo<int, returnsVoid> a; // ok
}
```

However, when I change the return type of the second template parameter to `auto` (as explained in [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65915344)), I get an error:

```
void returnsVoid(int x) { }

template <typename T, auto (*Func)(T)>
struct foo {
    void bar(T t) { Func(t); }
};

int main(int, char *[]) {
    foo<int, returnsVoid> a; // error: unable to deduce ‘auto (*)(T)’ from ‘returnsVoid’
                             // note:   mismatched types ‘T’ and ‘int’
}
```

Why does this no longer work with an `auto` return type?

I'm using g++ 9.3.0 on an Ubuntu Linux machine. A similar error occurs in clang 10.

Comment: I find this question very interesting, particularly from the perspective of what the standard actually says here (as compared to that this is likely a gcc bug): thus adding the language-lawyer tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is gcc's bug. ([Bug 83417](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=83417))

It seems gcc failing deducing the type of `auto` when using the 1st template parameter `T` as function parameter; you can use [`std::type_identity`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/type_identity) (since C++20) to exclude it from participating in [template argument deduction](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_argument_deduction#Non-deduced_contexts).

```
// workaround for gcc
template <typename T, auto (*Func)(std::type_identity_t<T>)>
struct foo {
    void bar(T t) { Func(t); }
};
```

[LIVE](https://wandbox.org/permlink/1oSKYu6SptsvZ1lw)

BTW: [Clang 10](https://wandbox.org/permlink/FMYZVWOgEz8TSI7L) seems working well.

Comment: @TypeIA I think it's gcc's bug, but not sure. I can't think of anything prevent the deduction from working in this case. BTW: `std::type_identity` is easy to implement if your compiler doesn't support C++20.

Comment: @TypeIA Confirmed. This should be gcc's bug. https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=83417

Answer (score 2):

<sub>*All standard references below refer, unless noted otherwise, to [N4861 (March 2020 post-Prague working draft/C++20 DIS)](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/).*</sub>

---

#### TL;DR;

Jump to the *A workaround to mitigate the GCC bug* section in the bottom of this post for a workaround, accepted by GCC and Clanng, which still relies of deduction of dependent types to avoid a client having to specify a second template argument for the actual type of the function parameter associated with the "main" template argument; namely the function pointer used associated non-type template parameter.

#### Standardese

As per [[temp.deduct.type]/13](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/temp.deduct.type#13):

> When the value of the argument corresponding to **a non-type template
> parameter `P` that is declared with a dependent type** is deduced from
> an expression, **the template parameters in the type of `P` are deduced
> from the type of the value.** [ *Example:*
>
> ```
> template<long n> struct A { };
>
> template<typename T> struct C;
> template<typename T, T n> struct C<A<n>> {
>   using Q = T;
> };
>
> using R = long;
> using R = C<A<2>>::Q;  // OK; T was deduced as long from the
>                        // template argument value in the type A<2>
> ```
>
> — *end example* ]

any dependent types in the declaration of a non-type template parameter that undergoes type deduction (from an expression) shall also be deduced from the associated argument for the non-type template parameter. It is also essential that [[temp.deduct.type]/5](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/temp.deduct.type#5), covering *the non-deduced contexts*, does not apply for general uses of dependent types within non-type template parameters that are function pointers; meaning in the OP's example, `T` is a dependent type and is thus deduced from the value of the argument to the non-type (function pointer) template parameter.

A common problem when a given, say, type template parameter is deduced from more than one source (e.g. as in the example of OP), is that deduction yields different types; e.g. as showing [in the following blog post](https://dfrib.github.io/non-deduced-contexts/):

> ```
> template<typename T>
> struct Foo { T t; };
>
> template<typename T>
> void addToFoo(Foo<T>& foo, T val) { foo.t += val; }
>
> int main() {
>     Foo<long> f{42};
>     addToFoo(f, 13); // error: no matching function for call to 'addToFoo'
>                      // note: candidate template ignored: deduced conflicting
>                      //       types for parameter T (long vs. int).
>     return 0;
> }
> ```

As has been shown in [@songyuanyao: answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65916419/4573247) (and as is shown also in the blog post), a type identity transformation trait can be used to intentionally place a given template parameter in a non-deduced context for cases where several deduction sources yields conflicting results.

However, the root cause of OP:s failure is not conflicting deduction results (this is a red herring), but rather GCC:s failure to correctly deduce template parameter from when another template parameter is deduced, where the former is present as a dependent type.

Thus, if we go back to [temp.deduct.type]/13, for the following class template and subsequent partial specialization:

```
// #1
template <auto>
struct A { static void dispatch() = delete; };

// #2
template <typename T, void (*fun)(T)>
struct A<fun> {
    static void dispatch() {
        T t{};
        fun(t);
    }
};
```

the following:

```
A<f>::dispatch(); // #3
```

is well-formed if `f` is a function with a single argument (of a type that is default-constructible) which returns `void`, e.g.

```
void f(int) { std::cout << "void f(int)\n"; }
// -> #3 is well-formed
```

as this will match the partial specialization at `#2`, deducing `T` to `int` and the non-type template parameter (which decides the specialization blueprinted by the primary template), which is dependent on `T` in this partial specialization, to `void(*)(int)`.

On the other hand, `#3` is ill-formed if `f` does not return `void`, as the partial specialization at `#2` is no longer viable.

```
void f(int) { std::cout << "int f(int)\n"; }
// -> #3 is ill-formed
```

The key here is that:

- the partial specialization at `#2` applies only for template arguments to `A` which match the second (non-type) template parameter of the specialization, and
- the first template parameter of the specialization,`T`, is deduced from the deduction of the second (non-type) template parameter, as `T` is a dependent type in the declaration of the second template parameter.

Both GCC and Clang works as expected for the two cases above.

Now, if we consider the similar example as to that of `#1` and `#2` above:

```
// #4
template <auto>
struct B { static void dispatch() = delete; };

// #5
template <typename T, auto (*fun)(T)>
struct B<fun> {
    static void dispatch() {
        T t{};
        fun(t);
    }
};

// ... elsewere
// #6
B<f>::dispatch();
```

the same argument as above applies:

- if template argument `f` refers to a function (now with less restrictions) that has a single argument (of a type that is default-constructible), then the partial specialization at `#5` is viable, and its second non-type template parameter, which contains its first type template parameter as a dependent type, shall be used to deduce the latter.

The significant difference in this case is that the type of the non-type template parameter itself undergoes [[temp.arg.nontype]/1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/temp.arg.nontype#1):

> If the type `T` of a template-parameter contains a placeholder type
> ([dcl.spec.auto]) or a placeholder for a deduced class type
> ([dcl.type.class.deduct]), the type of the parameter is the type
> deduced for the variable `x` in the invented declaration
>
> ```
> T x = template-argument ;
> ```
>
> If a deduced parameter type is not permitted for a template-parameter
> declaration ([temp.param]), the program is ill-formed.

but [temp.deduct.type]/13 still applies the same, and we may not that [temp.deduct.type]/13 was actually added as part of [P0127R2](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0127r2.html) (*Declaring non-type template parameters with `auto`*) which introduced placeholder types for non-type template parameters for C++17.

Thus, the core issue is that GCC fails to perform dependent type deduction (as specified in [temp.deduct.type]/13) when the non-type template parameter in whose declaration the dependent type (to be deduced) is present is a function pointer (or, as shown in the [linked to GCC bug report](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=83417), as pointer to member) AND the non-type template parameter is declared with a placeholder type (`auto`).

[@songyuanyao: answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65916419/4573247) shows a workaround to this bug, applied to OP's example, simply making the dependent type non-dependent, as the associated template parameter can be deduced from elsewhere (namely from the first template argument in OP's example). This would not work for the examples above, where we rely *solely* on the dependent type deduction in the deduction of the non-type template parameter to find the type of the type template parameter (which is the dependent type in the former).

For an actual client API, requiring the client to explicitly specify the type of the argument to the function which is provided as another argument, when the former is entirely deducible from the latter, is arguably redundant design, and opens up for client confusion when providing conflicting arguments for these two template parameters. Thus, we'd arguably like to fall back on the partial specialization technique shown above, but as shown in these answers, GCC fails us in this regard in case we'd like the client to not be restricted to a specific return type.

#### A workaround to mitigate the GCC bug

We can work our way around this, however, by using the same approach as above, still relying on [temp.deduct.type]/13, but by using an additional type template parameter (for the return type) in the partial specialization:

```
#include <iostream>

template <auto>
struct C { static void dispatch() = delete; };

template <typename T, typename Return, Return (*fun)(T)>
struct C<fun> {
    static void dispatch() {
        T t{};
        fun(t);
    }
};

void f(int) { std::cout << "void f(int)\n"; }
int g(int) { std::cout << "int f(int)\n"; return 0; }

int main() {
    C<f>::dispatch();
    C<g>::dispatch();
}
```

The client will not need to worry about the additional template parameters of the partial specialization, as they entirely deducible via the third non-type template parameter of the specialization, in whose declaration they are dependent. This final example is accepted by both GCC and Clang.

Comment: Thanks for the very detailed and comprehensive answer. The partial specialization workaround is evil voodoo.

Answer (score 2):

This is [CWG2476](http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/cwg_active.html#2476): [dcl.spec.auto]/2 requires that `auto` used as (part of) a return type without a *trailing-return-type* appear only where the function declarator declares a function.  The template parameter declaration doesn’t do that, so it’s **invalid**.  One could argue that /5 allows it in a template parameter’s *decl-specifier-seq* regardless, but that doesn’t make sense because it would deprive the following of meaning:

```
template<auto g() -> int>
int f() {return g();}
```

That said, the deduction rules would work here, so this is a **defect** in the wording that will probably be fixed by saying that return type deduction just doesn’t happen in the cases where `auto` is allowed for other reasons.

Comment: But in this case the type of the non-type template parameter, say `U`, which contains a placeholder type, is a pointer to function, and not a function. Would not [\[temp.arg.nontype\]/1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/temp.arg.nontype#1) apply here? If we remove the noise of the OP:s example and consider a non-type template parameter, which is a pointer to function: `template<auto (*g)()> int f() { return g(); }`. As per [temp.arg.nontype]/1 the type of this non-type template parameter, say `T`, is deduced from the invented declaration `T x = template-argument`. ...

Comment: ... Similarly (but not equivalent) would be the example of placeholder type deduction for when using `auto` in a pointer to function variable, e.g. `auto (*h)() = some_function;`. This is well-formed, right? Possibly this is what you mean by _"[...] that could be fixed by saying that return type deduction just doesn’t happen in the cases where auto is allowed for other reasons."_ though? I'm leaning towards, however, interpreting from [dcl.spec.auto] that return type deduction does not apply for the case of function pointers, and that these solely falls under regular type deduction. Thoughts?

Comment: @dfrib: The problem is that [dcl.spec.auto]/2 doesn’t *check* whether it’s a function declaration; it *requires* that it be one if a function declarator is involved.  It’s like the rule that you can’t write `template<int G(auto)> void f(G);`; it’s just not supported for deduction there even though we know how that would work.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I will have to read up more on this. The topic seems to (arguably) confuse implementors as well, towards leniency, as both Clang, GCC and MSVC accepts `auto (*h)() = f;` (which should be a diagnosable error, as per your argument above). Could it be that a DR could be appropriate to move towards a ruling that follows that of the implementors (apparent) approach?

Comment: Consulting with CWG identifies this as [CWG1892](http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/cwg_defects.html#1892), which was resolved improperly in C++14 when the deduced-return-type feature was introduced.  That’s probably enough to categorize it as a defect now.

Comment: Thanks. T.b.h. I don't entirely follow the (very brief) discussion of CWG1892, but it seems to focus on (given the examples) function declarators, for which my knowledge is shallow. I was under the impression that a pointer to function is not a function declarator ([dcl.decl]/1, [dcl.fct]); e.g. `int (*h)() = nullptr` is a variable declarator and not a function declarator. Am I wrong here? (If not, `auto (*h)() = f;` would not be banned under CWG1892, unless the actual intent was to apply it also for non-function declarators where the deduced type is part of a function type).

Comment: I moved out the "is a pointer to function (sometimes/always) a function declarator" to [a separate question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66009034/4573247).

Answer (score 1):

As already stated by @songyuanyao this seems to be a gcc bug.

For <= c++17 One solution is to move type T form function signature to non-deduced context:

```
template <typename T>
struct identity { using type = T; };
```

and then

```
template <typename T, auto (*Func)(typename identity<T>::type)>
struct foo {
    void bar(T t) { Func(t); }
};
```

Another approach is to change design and to move to a member function template. The auto type deduction works in this case:

```
void returnsVoid(int) { }

template <typename T>
struct foo {
    template <auto (*Func)(T)>
    void bar(T t) { Func(t); }
};

int main(int, char *[]) {
    foo<int> a; 
    a.bar<returnsVoid>(3);
}
```

[Live](https://godbolt.org/z/vb3r7j)

Comment: +1 for the novel refactoring into a nested template. A variant of this (moving the entire struct into a containing struct which has the `T` template parameter while the inner struct has the function pointer template parameter) works for me, although I think the `std::type_identity` route is better if available.