# Is a pointer to function (sometimes/always?) a function declarator?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, auto, type-deduction

<sub>*(This question has been broken out from [the discussion to this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65930813/4573247), which highlights [CWG 1892](http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/cwg_defects.html#1892))*</sub>

---

Some paragraphs of the standard applies specific rules to *function declarators*; e.g. [[dcl.spec.auto]/3](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/dcl.spec.auto#3) regarding placeholder types [**emphasis** mine]:

> **The placeholder type can appear with a function declarator** in the *decl-specifier-seq*, *type-specifier-seq*, *conversion-function-id*, or *trailing-return-type*, in any context where such a declarator is valid. If the function declarator includes a *trailing-return-type* ([dcl.fct]), that *trailing-return-type* specifies the declared return type of the function. **Otherwise, the function declarator shall declare a function.** [...]

restricts where placeholder types may appear with(in) a function declarator. We may study the following example:

```
int f() { return 0; }
auto (*g)() = f;  // #1
```

which both GCC and Clang accepts, deducing `g` to `int(*)()`.

- Is a pointer to function (sometimes/always?) a function declarator?
- Or, alternatively, applied to the example, should `#1` be rejected as per [[dcl.spec.auto]/3](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/dcl.spec.auto#3), or does the latter not apply here as a pointer to function is not a function declarator (instead allowing `#1` as per [[dcl.spec.auto]/4](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/dcl.spec.auto#4) regarding variable type deduction from initializer)?

---

The rules for what is a given declarator is not entirely easy to follow, but we may note that, from [[dcl.decl]/1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/dcl.decl#1)

> A declarator declares a single variable, function, or type, within a declaration.

that a given declarator is either any of a *variable declarator*, a *function declarator* or a *type declarator*.

- [[dcl.ptr]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/dcl.ptr) covers (variable) declarators that are pointers, but does not explicitly (/normatively) mention pointers to functions, albeit does so non-normatively in [[dcl.ptr]/4](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/dcl.ptr#4.sentence-2)
- [[dcl.fct]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/dcl.fct) covers function declarators but does not mention function pointers as part of function declarations, other than a note that function types are checked during assignment/initialization to function pointers (which is not relevant for what a function declarator is)

My interpretation is that `#1` is legal (as per the current standard), as it falls under a variable declarator. If this is actually correct, then the extended question (from the linked thread) is whether

```
template<auto (*g)()> 
int f() { return g(); }
```

is legal or not (/intended to be legal or not as per CWG 1892); as the template parameter arguably contains a declarator that is a function pointer declarator, and not a function declarator.

We may finally note, as similarly pointed out in the linked to answer, that

```
template<auto g()>  // #2
int f() { return g(); }
```

is arguably ill-formed (although this example is also accepted by both GCC and Clang), as the non-type template parameter at `#2` is a function declarator and is thus used in an illegal context as per [dcl.spec.auto]/3, as it does not contain a trailing return type and does not declare a function.

Comment: My understanding is that `auto (*g)() = f;` works for the same reason `auto x = 42;` works, not because it has something to do with functions. In fact, [one can write](https://godbolt.org/z/6GW6dP) `auto x = 42, (*g)() = f;`

Comment: @IgorTandetnik For clarity: we are discussing _well-formed_ rather than what _works_ (these are commonly in conflict in language-lawyer questions). I am also leaning towards `auto (*g)() = f` being well-formed, the key being that there is no function declarator involved in its declaration (such that [dcl.spec.auto]/3 _does not apply_). Your second example is [\[dcl.decl\]/3](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/dcl.decl#3) and is not significant here; whether the single declarator being discussed is well-formed or ill-formed (in isolation or as part of a decl. with several declarators).

Comment: _there is no function declarator involved in its declaration_ How `auto (*g)()` is parsed then?

Comment: @LanguageLawyer "_leaning towards_ [...] there is no function declarator" - this is my key question: is there in fact a function declarator involved here? / Is a pointer to function, or does it contain, a function declarator? Please consider posting an answer if you have an argument for "yes it is/does". (In which case [dcl.spec.auto]/3 would arguably apply, implying that `#1` is ill-formed?).

Comment: _is there in fact a function declarator involved here? / Is a pointer to function, or does it contain, a function declarator?_ I don't know a way to parse `auto (*g)()` without [dcl.fct]. `auto (*g)()` has form `T D1()`.

Comment: I think the wording `function declarator` is vague here.There's no formal definition for `function declarator`. Does it mean the declarator declares a function or the declarator has the form D1(parameter-declaration-clause )cv-qualifier-seq<opt> ref-qualifier
<opt> noexcept-specifier<opt> attribute-specifier-seq<opt>?It appears to me that "A declarator declares a single variable, function, or type, within a declaration." seems to refer to the former. However, `auto (*g)()` does not declare a function as per [function](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/dcl.dcl#def:function_declaration)

Comment: @jackX I agree. Although LanguageLawyer has valid point regarding parsing about, that would arguably cover "the reasonable intent" of declarators in this context, rather than what the actual standard says here: using the term "function declarator" in a strict rule whilst the term itself can arguably be interpreted ambiguously.

Comment: @dfrib We could give an example for contrast, `int* fun()`, It first matches the form of a pointer, `T D` where D has the form `* attribute-specifier-seq<opt> cv-qualifier-seq
<opt> D1` , Can it be called `pointer declarator`? I don't think. Instead, the declarator indeed declares a function here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The confusion here arises from two different meanings of "declarator": one is the portion of a declaration (after the specifiers) that pertains to one **entity** (or typedef-name), while the other is any of the several **syntactic** constructs used to form the former kind.  The latter meaning gives rise to the grammar productions *ptr-declarator* (which also covers references) and *noptr-declarator* (which includes functions and arrays).  That meaning is also necessary to give any meaning to a **restriction** that a "function declarator shall declare a function".  Moreover, if we took the variable declaration

```
auto (*g)() = /*…*/;
```

to not involve a "function declarator" for the purposes of [dcl.spec.auto.general]/3, we would not be able to write

```
auto (*g)() -> int;
```

which is universally accepted (just as is the similar example in the question).

Moreover, while the statement that checks whether "the function declarator includes a *trailing-return-type*" inevitably refers to an **overall** *declarator* (which is what supports a *trailing-return-type*), it does so in its capacity as a "declaration operator" because it still allows the above cases with nested use of such operators.  (What that limitation forbids is just

```
auto *f() -> int*;
```

where deduction would work but isn't performed at all here because it would always be useless.)

Meanwhile, there is some evidence, beyond implementation consensus, that the answer to the higher-level question is that `auto` in these cases **should** be allowed: [dcl.spec.auto.general]/1 says that `auto` in a function parameter serves to declare a generic lambda or abbreviated function template "if it is not the `auto` *type-specifier* introducing a *trailing-return-type*" rather than if it is not used with a function declarator at all.

Comment: Such as `auto *fun()`, the form of the complete declarator first  matches [dcl.ptr] , which will decomposes it to `* D1` for getting the "derived-declarator-type-list", hence "auto D1" will matche [dcl.fct] which involve **function declarator**, Hence [dcl.spec.auto.general]/3 will require the declaration that include the  **function declarator** to declare a function. As the declaration do, it's a function declaration, So, it obeys the rule. Is this understanding Right?

Comment: Instead, for `auto (*ptr)()`, the form of the complete declarator first matches [dcl.fct] which involves the function declarator, however [dcl.fct] will decompose it to `auto (*ptr)`to get "derived-declarator-type-list" for determining what the declaration is. Eventually, the declaration that include the **function declarator** does not declare a function(it declares a pointer), So, it violates [dcl.spec.auto.general]/3, Right?

Comment: @jackX: The term “involve” is a bit loose, of course, but that sounds right.

Comment: Thanks. It seems that we understand the wording `function declarator` as the complete declarator that appears in a **function declaration** in common sense, as you said for the first meaning of "declarator". I think it's necessary to clarify [dcl.spec.auto.general]/3. Such as, If the function declarator includes a trailing-return-type ([dcl.fct]), that trailing-return-type specifies the declared return type of the function. Otherwise, the complete declarator of a declaration that comprises function declarators shall declare a function.

Comment: `auto *fun()`, In my mind, for this declaration, the type specifier is `auto` and its complete declarator is `* fun()`, which shall be called pointer declarator [dcl.ptr](I'm not sure, just analogy from function declarator[dcl.fct]). The complete declarator `*fun()` declares a function rather than `fun()` does, Right? Hence, I think [dcl.spec.auto.general]/3(namely, "Otherwise, the function declarator shall declare a function") should be clarified. as I said above.